# how to convert time with decimal point to time correctly using strtotime and date function?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to convert a 1.3 to 1:30 but when I use strtotime with date function 1.3 is becoming 1.03 !!!
whats is the solution for this?

this is what I am using and giving me the unexpected result:

```
<?php $time_from = 1.3; ?>
<?= date('h:i A', strtotime($time_from)); ?>
```

print_r or $opening_hours_array:

> Array (
>       [sunday_from] => 24.45
>       [sunday_to] => 1.3
>       [monday_from] => 2
>       [monday_to] => 2.15
>       [tuesday_from] => 3
>       [tuesday_to] => 3.15
>       [wednesday_from] => 4
>       [wednesday_to] => 4.15
>       [thursday_from] => 5
>       [thursday_to] => 5.15
>       [friday_from] => 6
>       [friday_to] => 6.15
>       [saturday_from] => 7
>       [saturday_to] => 1 )

what I am trying to do is show opening ours from and to:

```
 <?php
$days_of_week = array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
            for ($index = 0; $index < count($days_of_week); $index++) {
                $pos = strpos($opening_hours_array[strtolower($days_of_week[$index]) . '_from'], '.');
                if ($pos === false) {
                    $time_from = $opening_hours_array[strtolower($days_of_week[$index]) . '_from'].'.00';
                }else{
                    $time_from = $opening_hours_array[strtolower($days_of_week[$index]) . '_from'];
                }
                $pos = strpos($opening_hours_array[strtolower($days_of_week[$index]) . '_to'], '.');
                if ($pos === false) {
                    $time_to = $opening_hours_array[strtolower($days_of_week[$index]) . '_to'].'.00';
                }else{
                    $time_to = $opening_hours_array[strtolower($days_of_week[$index]) . '_to'];
                }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried a easy string replace . (dot) with : ?

Comment: I Want the result in the 'h:i A' format

Comment: "1.3" is in no way any officially recognized time format. Don't expect it to "just work". Use actually supported formats.

Comment: Let's say that in php everything is a string... after that you can manipulate the 1.3 how you want, than make a code to transform it to 1:30 and then make a date from it. like replacing the dot with : and if the second part (after an explode maybe) has length < 2 you can add a ending 0.

Comment: How did you end up with `1.3` in the first place?

Comment: I would've read that as 1.3 hours, i.e. 1 hour 18 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution would be:

```
$pos = strpos($opening_hours_array[strtolower($days_of_week[$index]) . '_from'], '.');
                if ($pos === false) {
                    $time_from = $opening_hours_array[strtolower($days_of_week[$index]) . '_from'].'.00';
                }else{
                    $time_from = $opening_hours_array[strtolower($days_of_week[$index]) . '_from'];
                    $time_from = (strlen($time_from)==3)?$time_from.'0':$time_from;
                }
                $pos = strpos($opening_hours_array[strtolower($days_of_week[$index]) . '_to'], '.');
                if ($pos === false) {
                    $time_to = $opening_hours_array[strtolower($days_of_week[$index]) . '_to'].'.00';
                }else{
                    $time_to = $opening_hours_array[strtolower($days_of_week[$index]) . '_to'];
                    $time_to = (strlen($time_to)==3)?$time_to.'0':$time_to;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Goikiu suggested the following code should do the trick

```
$time_from = 1.3;
$time_from = (strlen($time_from)==3)?$time_from.'0':$time_from;
echo date('h:i A', strtotime($time_from));

But there are other situations like 

$time_from = 1 ; 

The code needs to check for those as well.
```